# Error: Uncaught (in promise) TezosOperationError: (temporary) proto.017-PtNairob.tez.subtraction_underflow

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, nft

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise) TezosOperationError: (temporary) proto.017-PtNairob.tez.subtraction_underflow
```

I know this error is caused by a subtraction resulting in a negative number, but i'm just trying a simple code and can't avoid this.
My code:
import smartpy as sp

```
FA2 = sp.io.import_script_from_url("https://legacy.smartpy.io/templates/fa2_lib.py")

class Token(FA2.Admin, FA2.MintFungible, FA2.Fa2Fungible):
    def __init__(self, admin, **kwargs):
        FA2.Fa2Fungible.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        FA2.Admin.__init__(self, admin)

class Marketplace(sp.Contract):
    def __init__(self, token, metadata, admin):
        self.init(
            token=token,
            metadata=metadata,
            admin=admin,
            data = sp.big_map(
                tkey=sp.TNat,
                tvalue=sp.TList(
                    sp.TRecord(
                        holder=sp.TAddress,
                        author=sp.TAddress,
                        amount=sp.TMutez,
                        token_id=sp.TNat,
                        editions=sp.TNat,
                        collectable=sp.TBool))),
            token_id=0)
    @sp.entry_point
    def send(self, params):
        total_price = sp.utils.nat_to_tez(params.total_price)
        sp.send(params.account, sp.split_tokens(total_price, 90, 100))
```

In front-end, i call like this:

```
...
const op = await contract.methods.send(accountx, 100000).send(100000)
...
```

Where the 100000 is what i'm trying to send and accountx is account to send.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by ojuswi-rastogi, the error you're seeing arises from the use of `sp.send`, as it attempts to send 90000 tez instead of mutez. This is because you're converting the input of 100000 (of type nat) to tez using `sp.utils.nat_to_tez()`.

Instead of this conversion, it would be more appropriate to use the mutez type directly. However, I'd advise against using a parameter to specify the number of tez sent to your entry point. The reason is, a sender could specify any arbitrary number, which might not correspond to the actual amount sent.

Instead, you should utilize `sp.amount`, which gives you the exact number of mutez sent to the entry point. Here's a modified version of your code:

```
@sp.entry_point
def send(self, param):
    sp.send(params.account, sp.split_tokens(sp.amount, 90, 100))
```

Answer (score -1):

It's easier to debug it if you write some SmartPy tests for it. So, here you go:

```
@sp.add_test(name = 'Test')
def test():
    admin = sp.test_account('admin')
    sc = sp.test_scenario()

    token = Token(
        admin = admin.address,
        metadata = sp.big_map({"": sp.bytes('0x')})
    )
    sc += token

    marketplace = Marketplace(
        token = token.address,
        metadata = sp.big_map({"": sp.bytes('0x')}),
        admin = admin.address
    )
    sc += marketplace

    token.set_administrator(marketplace.address).run(sender = admin.address)

    marketplace.send(
        account = admin.address,
        total_price = 100000
    ).run(sender = admin.address, amount = sp.mutez(100000))
```

The error is coming at `sp.send` because it is trying to send 90000 tez instead of mutez. This is happening because we are sending 100000 nat, which is converted to 100000 tez using `sp.utils.nat_to_tez()`. So, the easiest solution is use `nat_to_mutez` instead of `nat_to_tez`. Like this:

```
total_price = sp.utils.nat_to_mutez(params.total_price)
```

Also, I'm not aware of your entire use case. But, you may also check `sp.amount` ([Link](https://legacy.smartpy.io/docs/types/mutez#get-transferred-amount)) which you can use to get the amount of mutez that is sent to the contract in a transaction.